# "extra fields not permitted" when subclassing model with private fields

Tags: python, python-3.x, pydantic

I have two classes:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, Extra

class Foo(BaseModel):
    a: str
    class Config:
        extra = Extra.forbid

class Bar(Foo):
    _secret: str
```

When I try initializing `Bar`:

```py
Bar(a='a', _secret='b')
```

I get the following error:

```
pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 1 validation error for Bar
secret
  extra fields not permitted (type=value_error.extra)
```

- This works fine if `Bar` is just subclassed off `BaseModel`, however I need it subclassed off of Foo for a variety of other reasons
- This works fine if `_secret` is just `secret`, but its really something I'd prefer to have as a hidden attribute
- This works fine if `Foo` does not have `Extra.forbid`, but its in a library that I'm importing and cannot change.

I'm not sure what else to try, any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

By default, Pydantic basically disregards underscored attributes completely. They are not added as **fields** to the model. In this case, arbitrary non-field attributes are also forbidden via the `extra` setting. If you now try to pass `_secret="b"` to the constructor, you get an error message because `_secret` is not a field and you tried to pass an "extra" value.

To solve this, you can override the `__init__` method and set your `_secret` attribute there, but take care to call the parent `__init__` with all other keyword arguments. In addition, you will need to declare `_secret` to be a [private attribute](https://docs.pydantic.dev/usage/models/#private-model-attributes), either by assigning `PrivateAttr()` to it or by configuring your model to interpret all underscored (non-class-)attributes as private.

This works:

```py
from typing import Any
from pydantic import BaseModel, Extra


class Foo(BaseModel):
    a: str

    class Config:
        extra = Extra.forbid


class Bar(Foo):
    _secret: str

    def __init__(self, _secret: str, **kwargs: Any) -> None:
        self._secret = _secret
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    class Config:
        underscore_attrs_are_private = True


bar = Bar(a="a", _secret="b")
print(bar)          # a='a'
print(bar._secret)  # b
```

The only downside I can see is that this seems to break some of the functionality of the Pydantic PyCharm plugin for suggesting `__init__` parameters. But that is not too dramatic IMO.

If you want to avoid overriding the `__init__` method, you will have to write some setter method for `_secret` instead, but it still must be declared as a private attribute.